# Catching HikariCP connection leak events

Tags: hikaricp, spring-boot-2

I am trying to send alerts when connection leaks occur from hikaricp.
I got to the point where I can see exception logs. But I am unable to catch those exceptions in a meaningful way so I can build a message and send as email.

I don't want to use generic @ExceptionHandler because HikariCP builds a generic exception and throws it. I want to be able to access underlying DataSource objects etc. so I can build a meaningful message.

```
[2023-09-06 05:11:01.137] WARN  [HikariPool-24--[DBConfig.class]--ReadOnly housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered for org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@443be07d on thread taskExecutor-2, stack trace follows
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.support.ProxyDataSource.getConnection(ProxyDataSource.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
    at com.company.solr.SolrImportationTask.getDelta(SolrImportationTask.java:233)
    at com.company.solr.SolrImportationTask.run(SolrImportationTask.java:141)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Is there a way to capture connection leak exception? I can add any other dependency on top of HikariCP, if you recommend them.

Comment: Easiest way is to implement an APM / Incident response tool (like Dynatrace/PagerDuty) on top of your application which segregate the logs and sends an alert. We have implement PagerDuty which send us an alert by checking the logs. If you wants to develop your own solution it will be a big task. Indigenous solution looks like you have to filter the logs at Logback level and trigger an event which sends an email.

Comment: @MohitSharma why can't I enclose entity manager creation (I manually create it from factory) and see if it gets a connection from hikari?
I debugged the code and saw the entity manager (essentially a hibernate session) borrows a connection when it is created. I can run a separate thread and if it is not created, then new monitor thread will throw error. That way I can check connection leak right?

Comment: If you want to implement this, seems it will also work. But creating custom code may impact as it depends on spring versions as well (incase you upgrade it near future and find changes in functionality). Easier will be to implement EvaluatorFilter in logback to filter out the Exception and use SMTPAppender to send the exception over mail.